# Cakephp3 passing an array to where condition

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working on this piece of code:

```
public function validateSelected($array = [1, 2])
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $samples = TableRegistry::get('Samples');
    $samples->query()
        ->update()
        ->set(['validate' => true])
        ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
            return $exp->in('id', $q);
        })
        ->execute();
}
```

The code is pretty much self explanatory, I want to update all the rows with id's that would be passed in an array to the function.

I've tested the code by doing this:

```
->where(function ($exp, $q) {
            return $exp->in('id', [1, 2, 3]);
        })
```

And its working fine but i cant pass the passed array parameter to this where condition as it gives a syntax error undeclared variable $array.

Any idea about how can i achieve this thing would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `use` language construct to include external variables into the anonymous function

```
 $ids = [1, 2, 3];
 ->where(function ($exp, $q) use($ids) {
        return $exp->in('id', $ids ]);
    })
```

but you can simply do

```
->where(['id IN'  => $ids])
```

or also

```
->where(['id' => $ids], ['id' => 'integer[]'])
```

see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses)

Comment: Thanks alot that worked. Can you please explain the purpose of the second parameter in the unknown function?

Comment: I guess it's because sometimes you need to access some $query methods inside the anonymous function. See [this paragraph](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements) for an example

Comment: Thanks for the response.